# using Microdata in index.php or single.php?

Tags: html, wordpress, microdata

I'm using wordpress and now wanna use microdatas for my posts.

But I'm confused that i should use them on index.php or just in single.php ?

(e.g. Author name, Rating, Author Image, ...)

Answer (score 1):

The `index.php` page is your Wordpress blog homepage.  `single.php` is an individual post that a user can click to from your homepage.

It might make sense to have rating and author information on your single.php page.

Comment: using them on index has any effects ?

Comment: They might appear on your homepage if the Wordpress template theme you are using displays those elements.  It seems like you should use them just on your single.php page.

Comment: i've rating of posts on my index too, as well as author name and used meta tag for author image. i wanna know if these also can be effective for google to be displayed ?

Comment: Yes.  The more original content you provide, the better.

Comment: I used them in both files for my own blog and Google is making sense of it in the webmaster tools. You can view the source at my [blog](http://blog.hompus.nl).